# How to link Socketio admin-ui with Flask-Scoketio?

Tags: python, node.js, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am currently working on a project that involves integrating Socket.IO Admin-UI with my Flask-SocketIO backend. The main objective is to obtain real-time data from the Socket.IO server and visualize it in the admin tool.

Specifically, I'm looking to address the following questions:

```
What is the most effective way to connect my Python Flask-SocketIO backend with Socket.IO Admin-UI, which is launched using Node.js with nodemon?

How can I establish a communication channel between my backend and the admin tool to fetch and display real-time data?

Are there any recommended libraries, modules, or best practices for achieving this integration seamlessly?
```

I would appreciate any insights, code examples, or guidance on how to make this integration work. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: The python-socketio package supports instrumentation that is compatible with the official Socket.IO Admin UI. I have not documented how to use this from Flask-SocketIO yet, but if you dig around you should be able to figure it out, as others have asked and shared solutions.